# Input type="textarea". Break line at the end of the line

Tags: html, css

A simple text area acting as in a post, I want the line to break at the of the post instead of overflowing on the same line.

```css
.post input {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <input type="textarea" placeholder="What's on your mind?" rows="4" cols="50">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code as a snippet so we can see what behavior you're getting and better understand the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I am new. How do I do that?

Comment: No problem, there should be an icon at the top of the text box that when hovered will show a tool tip that says: `JavaScript, HTML, CSS snippet Ctrl+M`.  That will bring up a codepen type editor to put in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<textarea>` element to more easily fix the issue :

```css
.post input{
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind?" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

`input[type="text"]` does not line break by design, which is why `textarea` is preferred for this application.